# no php.ini file found on windows (php 5.5.12)

Tags: php

We have a client with php v5.5.12 installed and we are trying to find the php.ini file that is being used when this is run from the command line (php-win.exe)

Running

```
php-win.exe --ini
```

returns nothing.

This is the top content of the output of phpinfo();

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => C:\Windows
Loaded Configuration File => (none)
Scan this dir for additional .ini files => (none)
Additional .ini files parsed => (none)
PHP API => 20121113
```

I've never seen this before! There are lots of modules enabled (but not all of them, which is what we are trying to fix) but can't find the config file that is being used.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there a php.ini file in `C:\Windows`?

Comment: Try `php.exe --ini` to see if that works

Comment: @ReynierPM - no difference.

Answer (score 0):

It was in C:\Windows. Strange it implies no .ini file was being loaded from there; and nothing in phpinfo();

Answer (score 0):

I am running wamp 2.5
when i run phpinfo I get
Configuration File (php.ini) Path

```
C:\Windows
```

Loaded Configuration File

```
C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin\php.ini
```

When I go to
C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin\php.ini
it is a symbolic link to
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\phpForApache.ini